# How to convert leaflet circle radius to nautical miles?

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet circle with a radius, how do I convert the radius to nautical miles in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for Leaflet's circle, the radius corresponds to meters (see [`L.circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#circle-radius)).  Then you can convert meters directly into nautical miles.

Note that `L.circle` is just an approximation:

> It's an approximation and starts to diverge from a real circle closer to poles (due to projection distortion).

To draw a gedetically accurate circle, use something like [Leaflet.Geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy).

Answer (score 0):

A quick JS function to convert meters to miles -

```
function metersToMiles(meters){
  if (isNaN(meters)){
    console.log("meters is not a number");
    return 0;
  }
  return meters/1852;
}
```

Also a good thing to note is that the draw tools for leaflet.draw have a way to draw a circle with nautical miles as the unit of measure -

```
draw: {
  circle: {
    metric: false,
    feet: false,
    nautic: true
  }
 }
```

[leaflet draw documentation link](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html)

It looks like there is a "readableDistance" on the L.GeometryUtil object too but I only used the code above so I am not sure how that would work.